# How to insert a section header into a uitableview from specific indices in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I have an NSMutableArray with 20 objects inside that displays data as needed in a uitableview. I want to insert a section header at index 5,10 and 15 (from the array). How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to split that NSMutableArray into 4 arrays (items 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 and 16-20) and create an NSMutableArray with the section headers. Then, you can use those arrays to populate the UITableView.

Comment: is there another way to do this without splitting it into different arrays?

Comment: You could try it with only one array - in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method, return 5 for sections 0 to 3, then, in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, look up the section ([indexPath section]) and fill the cell based on it (e.g. for section 1 use just [array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];, for section 2 use [array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] + 5]; and so on...